# Vínculos a perguntas diferentes não são nunca removidos?

Tags: suporte

Ao responder [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96493/215) eu achei que ela estava relacionada a [uma outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15534/215), mas depois percebi que não tinha nada a ver. Num intervalo de 5 minutos (*"grace period"*) eu concluí a resposta, percebi o erro e editei a resposta, de modo que não ficou registro algum de que a pergunta havia sido editada, nem links pras revisões anteriores.

Contudo, o vínculo entre as perguntas permanece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por quê? Existiria ainda alguma revisão anterior da minha resposta no site, mesmo que inacessível aos usuários comuns? Ou seria isso um bug? Aproveitando, o que fazer caso um usuário acrescente (acidental ou maliciosamente) vínculos que não se aplicam em absoluto a uma pergunta, bastaria avisar a um moderador para que ele os retire?

Comment: Eu chutaria que é cache, e que deve sumir mais tarde.

Comment: Ah, e moderadores não têm nenhum controle sobre o que aparece como "vinculado" ou "relacionado".

Comment: Ok.. quase 30 dias e nada do link sumir, fora que se eu fosse chutar diria que o script de limpeza rodaria ou no primeiro ou no último dia do mês. Parece que sua edição entrou por uma fenda do espaço-tempo, causou uma descontinuidade temporal e se firmou de forma irreversível no lista de perguntas vinculadas. Podemos esperar mais uns 10 dias (para não ter erro) e levar o assunto pro metão.

Answer (score 6):

Casos semelhantes onde links postados em comentários que acabaram sendo removidos ou em respostas que foram deletadas e não sumiram da lista de vinculados já foram várias vezes reportados no Meta SE.

De acordo com as discussões de lá, existem alguns [gatilhos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187734/229289) que acionam scripts para eliminar ou adicionar vínculos à pergunta, quando esse gatilho falha, existe um [script que roda a cada 30 dias](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64743/229289) que trata dessas situações. Essa informação é de 2011 e pode estar um pouco desatualizada, mas independente do tempo que vai levar para que ele rode é muito improvável que a SO tenha desabilitado essa funcionalidade.

Eu tentei reproduzir sem sucesso a situação que você citou. É possível que o seu caso tenha caído em alguma peculiaridade que o sistema que não tratou corretamente e agora estamos na mão do script dos 30 dias. Sugiro aguardamos para ver se ele funciona, caso contrário podemos reportar no Meta.SE como uma situação nova.

Answer (score 4):

Para mim ainda aparece vinculado (não deve ser cache).

Acho que isso é um mecanismo de ataque interessante. Se você quiser aumentar os views de sua pergunta (e com sorte os votos), basta fazer spam dela ao editar outras perguntas e respostas aleatoriamente e desfazer a edição logo em seguida dentro do *grace period*, adicionando então um monte de vinculações por aí. Dificilmente alguém vai perceber e isto não tem como ser consertado pelos moderadores!

E se você realizar esta ação por meio de um sockpuppet que use um IP diferente e que tenha a reputação necessária para fazer edições sem precisar passar pela fila de análise, então mesmo se algum moderador pegar o seu sockpuppet fazendo isso e suspendê-lo, você ficará impune.

Para dificultar ainda mais, se o sockpuppet fizer edições de fato corrigindo erros de ortografia por exemplo em meio a muitas edições de outros usuários, ficará quase impossível rastrear o que está acontecendo.

Ou seja, isto provavelmente é um bug bem grave.